# Why didn't the wildlings from GoT simply use boats to cross southward?

Tags: game-of-thrones

It seems rather silly to go through the whole effort of climbing a 700ft wall when they could simply use boats to go around it. I mean really, even Jon Snow did that when he came to try and rescue some of the wildlings before the got attacked. Are you telling me they couldn't figure out how to build rafts?

Comment: The wall is 700ft high not a 1000 ft.

Comment: This is a dupe as @Möoz has said but for what's its worth they did build rafts but that means going all the way to Eastwatch, building them, floating around *unseen*, then walking all the way back.